# Cassandra Python Driver: CRC Mismatch

Tags: python, cassandra, datastax-python-driver

I'm using [cassandra-driver](https://pypi.org/project/cassandra-driver/3.9.0/) (version 3.25.0) in Python 3.8.10 with a Cassandra 4 database. Sometimes when making requests to the database I get the following error. I've  pasted the relevant parts to the stacktrace below.

```
  File "XXXXX.py", line 17, in get_row
    session = cluster.connect(keyspace)
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 1667, in cassandra.cluster.Cluster.connect
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 1703, in cassandra.cluster.Cluster.connect
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 1690, in cassandra.cluster.Cluster.connect
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 3488, in cassandra.cluster.ControlConnection.connect
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 3533, in cassandra.cluster.ControlConnection._reconnect_internal
cassandra.cluster.NoHostAvailable: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'X.X.X.X:9042': ConnectionShutdown('CRC mismatch on header 8522. Received 80c00", computed 29cd26.')})
```

It's not necessarily frequent maybe every ~100 requests to the database. I only have one node setup in the Cassandra cluster. I'm not sure why a CRC checksum would be failing.

Comment: do you find any solution?

Comment: I created a wrapper function that takes in an argument 'retries' that says how many times to retry before throwing an error.